# How to break URLs in references into multiple lines

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, urls, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am using a 2 columns IEEEtran template. I have some long URLs in the references section. One of the URLs exceeds the column's width and does not break properly. How can I force URLs to break into multiple lines if the URL exceeds the column width?

Here is my main script:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
    \title{Title Here}  
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        Abstract here.
    \end{abstract}

    \section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}
    Some text here \cite{test}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

Here is the `ref.bib` script:

```
@misc{test,
    author = {Xing, Wang},
    title = {My Ref title},
    date = {2018},
    note = {Accessed Dec. 1, 208},
    url = { https://www.zzzzz.com/article/gggggg-aa-zzzzz-aaa-qqq-rrr-tttt-yyyy-8888-vvvvvv-qqqqqq-lllll-xxxxxx-oooooo-pppppp/},
    }
```

Comment: Load the `url` package, immediately *before* loading `hyperref`, with the options `hyphens` and `spaces`.

Comment: Have you tried it? I did exactly what you suggest. It gives me this error: `Option clash for package url. \usepackage`

Comment: @user9371654: Try `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens,spaces}{url}` and say `\usepackage{url}` only (without the options mentioned by Mico

Comment: @user9371654 - Did you notice the part of the instruction about loading `url` *before* `hyperref`? For sure, the only way I can manage to generate an "Option clash for package url" error message is if I load `url` after instead of before `hyperref`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Your suggestion works too -- as long as `url` is loaded before `hyperref`. :-)  If `url` is loaded after `hyperref`, there's no error message, but also no line-breaks of URL strings at hyphens...

Comment: @Mico: I was unsure whether other packages are involved also and try to load `url` as well with different options, leading to a clash eventually. I am not using links very often nor biber etc. as such I don't encounter such troublesome url problems

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - The `hyperref` package loads the `url` package automatically, but unfortunately without specifying the options `spaces` and `hyphens`, if it (the `url` package) hasn't been loaded already. That's why `url` must be loaded *before* `hyperref` if the options `spaces` and `hyphens` are meant to have an effect.

Comment: @Mico: I meant  packages **other** than `hyperref`. But yes, I have too limited knowledge about url typesetting features, so `\PassOptionsToPackage` was a try...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - It turns out that the query is a duplicate.

Comment: @Mico: After almost 10 years of TeX.SE?  Which query is not a duplicate of something? ;-)